# How can I move 2 blocks into a div?

Tags: layout, magento2.4

I'm trying to move the category image and description into a single div.

They're both in the catalog module under view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
 <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <container name="category.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-view" after="-">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.image" template="Magento_Catalog::category/image.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="image" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Category\Image</argument>
                        <argument name="output" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Category\Output</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.cms" template="Magento_Catalog::category/cms.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
```

This is my code

```
<move element="category.description" destination="category.view.container" before="category.image" />
```

Nothing is happening

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

As per default magento code category image and description is already in a single div which is "category-view". Both are calling in the same container. According to your "move element" code , it seems you are trying move description before category image and that will be achieve by below code.

In your theme's or module's catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="category.description" destination="category.view.container" before="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Please check and let me know if you have any query.